# Issues with changing a child object's properties using the Me.Controls() function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've been having a big issue with child and parent objects in vb.net (more specifically, in a VB.net Windows Forms Application). In the example code, I have assigned the contents of PieceArray (which each correspond to a PictureBox on the screen), and have added these values to a parent called Checkerboard (which is another PictureBox on which the other elements are placed upon).

For this code, it is very important that I use the Me.Controls() function, as it allows me to store a string with the same name as an object, and call the object from that string.

```
        Public PieceArray(7) As PictureBox
        PieceArray(0) = WK1
        PieceArray(1) = WQ1
        PieceArray(2) = WB1
        PieceArray(3) = WB2
        PieceArray(4) = WN1
        PieceArray(5) = WN2
        PieceArray(6) = WR1
        PieceArray(7) = WR2
        For x = 0 To 7
            Checkerboard.Controls.Add(PieceArray(x))
        Next
        Me.Controls(WR1).Location = New Point(0,0)
```

However, I have found that I am unable to access the objects once I have assigned them to a parent. I have tried multiple lines, such as:

```
'Me.Controls(WR1).Location = New Point(0,0)
'Me.Controls("WR1").Location = New Point(0,0)
'Me.Controls(Checkerboard(WR1)).Location = New Point(0,0)
'Checkerboard.Controls(WR1).Location = New Point(0,0)
'Checkerboard.Controls("WR1").Location = New Point(0,0)
```

However, the same issue persists. Please could someone advise me on this?

Many thanks,
Alfie

Note: I should add that if I put the line

```
Me.Controls("WR1").Location = New Point(0,0)
```

Before the for loop, the code performs perfectly, meaning that Me.Controls() can work on strings for the variable names, just not for ones that have a parent.

Comment: Control names are strings. You aren't setting the name of any PictureBox controls with the `.Name` property, either. Does this even compile? Where are `WK1` etc declared? You should specify Option Explicit in your project.

Comment: Were the picture box controls WK1, WQ1, etc. created at design time?

Comment: Yes @Mary , all the picture boxes were created at design time, that's why I haven't declared them. My apologies, I should have specified that I am using Microsoft Visual Studio (Windows Forms Application) to design and build my code.

Comment: It seems that your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting the correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Control.Controls` only returns the controls immediately contained within Control. In order to use the Controls property you'd need to run that on the "parents" instead of `Me`. Instead you can use the `Control.Controls.Find` function

```
Me.Controls.Find(WR1, True).Single().Location = New Point(0, 0)
' True as the second argument indicates you want to search all children
```

Comment: That code works absolutely perfectly - thank you so much!! :))